# Golang plugin in intellij-Idea not finding all files

Tags: intellij-idea, go

This relates to the go language plugin (version 0.9.15.3) for IntelliJ IDEA.

I have a directory structure in the following format:

- src/
- - fred/
- - - fred.go
- - bill/
- - - bill.go

In (say) bill/bill.go, I import fred.go, and the compiler picks up references to fred.Something (when run from the command line).

But IntelliJ IDEA does not recognise the references to fred.Something; they come up in red, and actions such as 'go to definition' do not work.

Is there anything I can do to make this work?

I don't want to upgrade to the alpha version of the plugin if I can help it, unless it is stable (in which case, it should not be alpha).

Comment: "When I import fred.go" ... I hope you mean `import "fred"`, you do not import individual *.go files by name.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use 0.9.15.3. The latest plugin should work properly for your case, if not please open a issue.

To get the latest plugin, please follow the instructions from here: https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin#pre-release-builds

Comment: I'm using version 15 of Intellij Idea and version 0.10.607 of the plugin now, and I still do not have this working properly. I cannot find any instructions that cover the current version of the plugin.